# MySQL и хранение пути к изображению

Tags: mysql

Создавая галерею, столкнулся с вопросом: правильно ли заносить имена файлов изображений в базу MySQL, а потом, обращаясь к базе, просматривать их в галерее? Не сильно ли это будет грузить сервер? И есть ли какие-либо другие решения этой задачи? Пользователь сможет изменять изображения и их всего 8 у каждого.

Comment: как вариант: раз число картинок ограничено и не много их имена с путём можно хранить одном поле через какой-нибудь разделитель, а уже в коде через split вставить в нужные места. Но тут есть трудности с логикой вставки/замены имени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос лишь в том сколько посетителей на сайте, и сколько фотографий одновременно будут открываться на странице. Если у вас тысячи посетителей онлайн и каждому одновременно грузятся все его фотографии то это одновременно несколько десятков тысяч запросов к БД, что, безусловно, будет подгружать сервер.

Так что считайте сами, насколько большой будет ваша БД и как много пользователей одновременно будут открывать фотографии.

Но не забывайте что основная нагрузка на сервер будет идти не в момент запроса пути файла из БД, а при загрузке самой картинки.

Comment: если несколько .. то нагружать будут нестолько сервер, сколько дисковую систему.

Answer (score 4):

Не советую хранить изображения в базе. Храните их просто в файлах, а в базу записывайте название файла.

Comment: Щито?
Изображение хранить в файлах это как? По моему в папке они хранятся.
Я не знаю можно ли хранить изображения в базе, но у меня хранятся там названия, вопрос был о загрузке сервера

Comment: Я имел ввиду хранить в папке как файлы и не заморачиваться с базой.

Comment: хранить картинки можно как нравится, к примеру cms OpenCMS всё хранить в базе. и ничуть от этого не страдает. если хранить картинки в фаловой системе (а в базе только имена) то надо предусмотреть структуру такого хранилища: хранить все файлы в одной папке - обеспечить огромные тормоза при доступе к каждому файлу.

Answer (score 2):

Та один запрос к базе данных, вытягивающий пути к изображениям - чем он там нагрузит сервер?

Answer (score 2):

Только в базе.

Отличие сайтов, подобных этому, от реальной жизни состоит в том, что отвечатели рассматривают каждую проблему, как новую, и воображают, как стали бы решать её сами. Но при этом эти идеи, по очевидным причинам, не проходят проверку практикой.

Если же посмотреть на все популярные скрипты фотогалерей в развитии, то становится ясно, что хранение имен(путей) файлов в базе - это **единственно возможный вариант.** Как только начинаются идеи "а как мне отсортировать файлы", "а как мне переименовать картинку", "а как мне сделать комментарии к фотографиям" - то сразу наступает прозрение.

Касательно же нагрузки на сервер - выборка имен файлов из БД **ничем не сложнее любого другого запроса.** То есть, задавать вопрос "не сильно ли это будет грузить сервер" - это все равно что спрашивать "это ничего, что моя машина требует бензин?" или "Можно ли есть суп ложкой?". Можно. Ничего. Не сильно.

Приложение, которое делает запросы к БД - это **нормально**.

Answer (score 1):

В мускуле естественно, что есть ID юзера. Так что вам мешает при загрузке файлов не переименовывать их под его ID? К примеру, у пользователя ID - 20, значит его фото будут:
20_1.jpg, 20_2.jpg, 20_N.jpg. В базе можете хранить только их кол-во

Answer (score 0):

под каждого пользователя создать папку на сервере с его id (создавать папку автоматически можно например при регистрации), в ней и хранить все его изображения, в базе только путь до картинки (/id3243254/p_9cadc3a2.jpg)